# recognize SCCollectionView in a method

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i have a method like this

-(CGSize) blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

in this i would like to recognize two different UICollectionView such as sccollectionview1, sccollectionview2. any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to make your collection views different custom subclasses of UICollectionView, e.g. MyCollectionViewType1 and MyCollectionViewType2. You don't give your subclass any special code; it's just so that you can compare the `class` of the collection view you get with one subclass or the other.

Comment: thank you matt for your kind reply. i already have two UICollectionViews which is SCCollectionView1, SCcollectionView2 using custom collectionViewCells. i would like to identify collectionview inside CGSize method like if(collectionView == SCColectionView1){ do something } else if(collectionView == SCColectionView2){do something}